# Ajax sending Get instead Post

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring

Well folks, I'm getting the error that suggests the title, I've been through several searches and here I am.

My jquery version is: 1.10.2

my Ajax Function:

```
    <script>
      function doPost() {
        var formData = JSON.stringify($("#form-titulo").serializeArray());
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "/titulos/editar/" + $("#codigoTitulo").val(),
          data: formData,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Erro ao editar título: " + textStatus);
          },
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

my Form attributes:

```
 <form
            id="form-titulo"
            action="/titulos/editar/{id}"
            method="POST"
            onSubmit="event.preventDefault(); doPost();"
          >
```

I can't figure it out what's is happening, but always I send the via Ajax I get 'GET" request is not supported

This is my last changes in code, i've been trying this for the last 2 hours, if u guys need more informations I'll be active in the pc.

[in the insomnia works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQOJQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks correct to me. As a workaround try the specific Ajax post() method:

```
function doPost() {
        var data = $("#form-titulo").serializeArray();
        $.post("/titulos/editar/" + $("#codigoTitulo").val(),
          data,
          function (result) {
            alert("result: " + result);
          }
        );
      }
```